# XS engine issue in HANA Studio

Tags: hana, hana-xs, hana-studio

I am trying to develop a **XS Project**. My XS engine is ***up and running***. If I do **http://hana.corp:8000**, then it is showing that my XS engine is up and running. But I am not able to run the .XS or .html file from the browser as I am getting **404-File not found** error. If I run in the localhost, it is perfectly running.

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this issue?

**Your help will be highly appreciated**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the XS Engine that the folder with your HTML file should be accessible from the Web.

To do so, place an (empty) `.xsapp` file in that folder.